# How to Mysqli Escape string without access to the db connection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to modify some code and I wanted to use mysqli instead of mysql if possible.   Here is what it looks like today.

```
$query = sprintf("select * from table where column = '%s';",mysql_escape_string($value));
$result = do_query_mysqli($query, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

the function do_query_mysqli is in another file and I don't want to modify that file if possible.   That function also includes $link to connect to the DB.

I do not have access to $link in the file I am modifying.

What is the best alternative to the code below if I want to achieve a similar result but I don't have access to $link?

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
```

Thanks!

Edit -- 
None of the answers and comments address my issue which is I am trying to reduce the risk of sql injection without having to change the function that executes the queries.  But I will look into the solutions suggested anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: if you really must, there is a function in the user notes of the manual page for https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php, you could use

Comment: I'm afraid you *will* have to change the function. There's no 100% safe way to do what you want without using the database connection. The current code structure is simply insufficient for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mysqli to avoid SQL injection I've found it's better to use bind_param and bind_result.

```
$select1 = $con->prepare("SELECT jobnumber ,starttime ,endtime, title from JobSheet WHERE starttime BETWEEN ? AND ?;");
$select1->bind_param('ss', $mondayMidnight, $sundayMidnight);
$select1->bind_result($jobnumber, $starttime, $endtime, $title);
$select1->execute();
```

It's also good practice to ONLY select the columns you're interested in to satisfy the query you're using. `SELECT * FROM ...` is a minefield and a program error waiting to happen (when someone alters the table).

bind_param doesn't allow for SQL injection as the SQL is already prepared.